# Configure Phusion Passenger 3.0.18 with RHEL 5.2 and Puppet 3.0.0

Tags: ruby, passenger, puppet

I am trying to configure Apache/Phusion Passenger under RHEL 5.2. So far the installation of the passenger module and mod_ssl for apache was successful but i am having issues trying to test a puppet client agent.

This is how my **passenger.conf** located on **/etc/httpd/conf.d** looks like

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.18
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

# you probably want to tune these settings
PassengerHighPerformance on
PassengerMaxPoolSize 12
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1500
# PassengerMaxRequests 1000
PassengerStatThrottleRate 120
RackAutoDetect On
RailsAutoDetect Off

Listen 8140

<VirtualHost *:8140>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP

        SSLCertificateFile      /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/xxxxx.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/xxxxx.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
        SSLCACertificateFile    /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
        # If Apache complains about invalid signatures on the CRL, you can try disabling
        # CRL checking by commenting the next line, but this is not recommended.
        SSLCARevocationFile     /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth  1
        # The `ExportCertData` option is needed for agent certificate expiration warnings
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

        # This header needs to be set if using a loadbalancer or proxy
        RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For

        RequestHeader set X-SSL-Subject %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
        RequestHeader set X-Client-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
        RequestHeader set X-Client-Verify %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}e

        DocumentRoot /etc/puppet/rack/public/
        RackBaseURI /
        <Directory /etc/puppet/rack/>
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My puppet configuration **/etc/puppet/puppet.conf**

```
[main]
    # The Puppet log directory.
    # The default value is '$vardir/log'.
    logdir = /var/log/puppet

    # Where Puppet PID files are kept.
    # The default value is '$vardir/run'.
    rundir = /var/run/puppet

    # Where SSL certificates are kept.
    # The default value is '$confdir/ssl'.
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
    ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
[agent]
    # The file in which puppetd stores a list of the classes
    # associated with the retrieved configuratiion.  Can be loaded in
    # the separate ``puppet`` executable using the ``--loadclasses``
    # option.
    # The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

    # Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
    # extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
    # The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

On the httpd server logs i can see the following warnings

```
[Mon Dec 03 13:53:08 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Dec 03 13:53:08 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `xxxxx' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 03 13:53:08 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Dec 03 13:53:08 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Dec 03 13:53:08 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `xxxxx' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 03 13:53:08 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I also get an html output from the client log when running *puppet agent --test*

```
The application has exited during startup (i.e. during the evaluation of config/environment.rb). The error message may have been written to the web server's log file. Please check the web server's log file (i.e. not the (Rails) application's log file) to find out why the application exited.
If that doesn't help, then please use the backtrace below to debug the problem.

Application root:
/etc/puppet/rack



    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util.rb  514 in `exit'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util.rb  514 in `exit_on_fail'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb   344 in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb 76  in `execute'
    config.ru   33  
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `instance_eval'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `initialize'
    config.ru   1   in `new'
    config.ru   1
```

*Config.ru*

```
# a config.ru, for use with every rack-compatible webserver.
# SSL needs to be handled outside this, though.

# if puppet is not in your RUBYLIB:
# $LOAD_PATH.unshift('/opt/puppet/lib')

$0 = "master"

# if you want debugging:
# ARGV << "--debug"

ARGV << "--rack"

# Rack applications typically don't start as root.  Set --confdir to prevent
# reading configuration from ~/.puppet/puppet.conf
ARGV << "--confdir" << "/etc/puppet"

# NOTE: it's unfortunate that we have to use the "CommandLine" class
#  here to launch the app, but it contains some initialization logic
#  (such as triggering the parsing of the config file) that is very
#  important.  We should do something less nasty here when we've
#  gotten our API and settings initialization logic cleaned up.
#
# Also note that the "$0 = master" line up near the top here is
#  the magic that allows the CommandLine class to know that it's
#  supposed to be running master.
#
# --cprice 2012-05-22

require 'puppet/util/command_line'
# we're usually running inside a Rack::Builder.new {} block,
# therefore we need to call run *here*.
run Puppet::Util::CommandLine.new.execute
```

This was working using the Webrick default webserver and it was connecting to the puppet clients without any issues.

Any other clues that can help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Can you share your /etc/puppet/rack/config.ru?

Comment: I just did add the file contents

Answer (score 0):

There was [a fix](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/commit/623fa028) made to the config.ru between 3.0.0 and 3.0.1 as a parameter was missing from the default file.  Although the error you're getting isn't clear, it's possible this is the issue.

The following line was added:

```
ARGV << "--vardir"  << "/var/lib/puppet"
```

Try grabbing the [full config.ru from Puppet 3.0.1](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/3.0.1/ext/rack/files/config.ru).

Comment: I got the same results when adding this new line. I will update my puppet version to 3.0.1 and see how it goes with the new config.ru

Comment: I have updated the puppet client and server to version 3.0.1. But i still have the same issue. I did copy the new config.ru from the new tarball and indeed have that --vardir line. Still is not working for me.

Comment: After the upgrade i am getting a lot of certificate errors on the /etc/https/logs/error_log 

[Thu Dec 06 15:58:36 2012] [error] Certificate Verification: Error (23): certificate revoked
[Thu Dec 06 16:26:44 2012] [error] Certificate Verification: Error (23): certificate revoked

When i run it manually using sudo puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose. It just works without any issues.